# How to render low resolution textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I have a low resolution image. It is 16 by 16 pixels. I want to use this texture in cycles. When I apply this texture to a mesh it becomes blurry. This is because blender uses linear pixel blending, I would want the pixel blending to be set to closest. I see no options in cycles to change this. I want to image to look blocky, even in cycles. How can maintain the low resolution of the image? I could create a larger version of the same image, but that would be a waste of disk space.

[image]  [image]

**[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27316)**